# How to limit class type parameter with specific tuples? (Scala 2.10.4)

Tags: scala, templates, tuples

I would like to limit type [R] with only specific tuples which are listed somewhere. My main goal is: to ensure that compiler raises an error if any other tuple rather than one of expected is passed to the following trait.

```
trait QV_Storable[R <: QV_Cue] {
    val prefix: String
    val tableName = prefix.concat(Random.alphanumeric take 8 mkString)
    def Make(rows: Iterable[R.storageColumns]): String 
}
```

Then I do expect `QV_Storable` accept only tuples listed in `SegmentCue` because it is subtupe of `QV_Cue`. Pay attention that I pass `R.storageColumns` to `Make(rows: Iterable[R.storageColumns])`. Thus, I do expect a way to access parameters of class type.

```
trait QV_Cue{
    type storageColumns <: Product
    type metaColumns <: Product
}
object SegmentCue extends QV_Cue {
    type storageCols = (CoreDataID, String)
    type metaCols = (Int, String, Date, Int)
}
```

Is there anyway to limit it this way? 
It would not be great to subtype from Tuple1, Tuple3, etc.

Comment: Can you explain your use-case? It's not clear (to me, anyway) what you're asking.

Comment: @Paul trait QV_Storable must accept only specific types of Tuples. e.g (Int, String), or (Int, Int, Int). If I would limit type [R <: Product] compiler will accept all types of tuples, whether I need only allowed.

Comment: That's not your use-case, just the question stated again. But maybe it's just me that can't see immedaitely why you want this.

Comment: @Paul, in my case I want to be sure that all values goes through the trait will be insertable in the specific tables or storage with conventional data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a type class, which only sufficient tuples implement:

```
trait Ok[T] {}

// (Int, Int) is Ok
implicit val tupleIntIntOk: Ok[(Int, Int)] = new Ok[(Int, Int)] {}

// (String, _) is Ok too
implicit def tupleStringAOk[A]: Ok[(String, A)] = new Ok[(String, A)] {}

trait QV_Storable[R] {
  def method(implicit rok: Ok[R]): Unit
  // ...
}
```

In this scenario you can't call `QV_Storable.method` if there aren't `rok` value of the right type in the scope.

This way you can create QV_Storable with any `R`, but can't actually use any without proper `Ok`.

---

A bit different approach is to make similar trick on type-level. Yet there aren't implicit resolution:

```
sealed trait Ok[T] {}

case class TupleIntIntOk() extends Ok[(Int, Int)]
case class TupleStringAOk[A]() extends Ok[(String, A)]

trait QV_Storable[R, OkR <: Ok[R]] {
  val prefix: String
  // ...
}

// compiles
val foo = new QV_Storable[(Int, Int), TupleIntIntOk] { val prefix = "xy" }

// doesn't
val bar = new QV_Storable[(Int, String), /* nothing to put here */] { val prefix = "bar "}
```

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the answer. I have tried first approach, but couldn't make it work as expected. Probably I am doing something wrong. Would you mind to look at it? I have edited your answer.

Comment: @CronAcronis In the first version you **can** state the type of `QV_Storable[R]` with wrong  `R`, but **you cannot** call `method`. The second version you **cannot** even state the invalid type, but there you need to be explicit.